# how to optimize a jquery function concatenating letter to identidicator

Tags: jquery, parameters

I would like to pass a char `x` as a parameter In the following function (`x = a`)

I would like to substitute all Identificators like `"#a1_field_box"` using char variable `x`

How can I cahnge `"#a1_field_box"` using var `x`? so if parameter is `b` I would get  `"#b1_field_box"`, if `x = 'c'` I would get `"#c1_field_box"` and so on

```
function ShowIfOther1()
{
    var x = 'a';    
    if ( $('#con1').prop('checked') )
    {
        $("#a1_field_box").show().fadeIn(500);  $("#a1_display_as_box").fadeIn(500); $("#field-a1").fadeIn(500);                                                
        $("#a2_field_box").show().fadeIn(500);  $("#a2_display_as_box").fadeIn(500); $("#field-a2").fadeIn(500);                                                
        $("#a3_field_box").show().fadeIn(500);  $("#a3_display_as_box").fadeIn(500); $("#field-a3").fadeIn(500);                                                
        $("#a4_field_box").show().fadeIn(500);  $("#a4_display_as_box").fadeIn(500); $("#field-a4").fadeIn(500);                                                
        $("#a5_field_box").show().fadeIn(500);  $("#a5_display_as_box").fadeIn(500); $("#field-a5").fadeIn(500);                                                
    } else {
        $("#a1_field_box").hide('slow');    $("#a1_display_as_box").hide('slow');$("#field-a1").hide('slow');
        $("#a2_field_box").hide('slow');    $("#a2_display_as_box").hide('slow');$("#field-a2").hide('slow');
        $("#a3_field_box").hide('slow');    $("#a3_display_as_box").hide('slow');$("#field-a3").hide('slow');
        $("#a4_field_box").hide('slow');    $("#a4_display_as_box").hide('slow');$("#field-a4").hide('slow');
        $("#a5_field_box").hide('slow');    $("#a5_display_as_box").hide('slow');$("#field-a5").hide('slow');
    }                       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `show()` in `.show().fadeIn(500)` is redundant. It can be removed as `fadeIn()` is `show() + animation`.
2. All the selectors can be combined and used as comma-separated, on which same operation is to be done. Eg. `fadeIn()` and `hide()`.
3. You can concat variables using `+` operator

Code:

```
function ShowIfOther1(x) {
    if ($('#con1').prop('checked')) {
        $('#' + x + '1_field_box, #' + x + '1_display_as_box, #field-' + x + '1, #' + x + '2_field_box, #' + x + '2_display_as_box, #field-' + x + '2, #' + x + '3_field_box, #' + x + '3_display_as_box, #field-' + x + '3, #' + x + '4_field_box, #' + x + '4_display_as_box, #field-' + x + '4, #' + x + '5_field_box, #' + x + '5_display_as_box, #field-' + x + '5').fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        $('#' + x + '1_field_box, #' + x + '1_display_as_box, #field-' + x + '1, #' + x + '2_field_box, #' + x + '2_display_as_box, #field-' + x + '2, #' + x + '3_field_box, #' + x + '3_display_as_box, #field-' + x + '3, #' + x + '4_field_box, #' + x + '4_display_as_box, #field-' + x + '4, #' + x + '5_field_box, #' + x + '5_display_as_box, #field-' + x + '5').fadeOut(500);
    }
}
```

And call it like

```
ShowIfOther1('a');
```

Also I would suggest to use same class names for each of those separate #id's and using `jQuery parent()` method you can show/hide easily with very less code.

Comment: Thanks for tips/insight :)

Comment: Nice example on how to optimize